# .htaccess, make all urls serve the same page secretly

Tags: php, .htaccess

Is there a way to make it so that htaccess will redirect all urls to the same page, unless it exists? In this case I want the redirect to be BEHIND THE SCENES. This means that the URL CANNOT change for the user. I need the data from the url, I'm just handling all the page stuff via PHP server-wise. Writing some crazy php stuff. ;)

My current code:

```
RewriteEngine On

#Remove www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "http\:\/\/example\.com\/" [R=301]

#Remove Ending Slash
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/phpmyadmin/$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ http://example.com/$1 [R=301]

#Get page from /page/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/page$
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/page%{REQUEST_URI} -f
RewriteRule ^ http://example.com/page_it_should_go_to.php [L]

DirectoryIndex header.php
```

Exactly what I need:

1. All pages, unless the exact url is a real place on the server or is in the location /page, need to serve example.com/page_it_should_go_to.php
2. phpMyAdmin needs to continue working
3. No www
4. No trailing slash on home

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aha! I figured out what was wrong.

Turns out it was multiple things! Here's what I got from a little more googling:

1. You can't have absolute urls, because that will redirect the user.
2. I had `RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/page%{REQUEST_URI} -f` left in there from back when I was redirecting to /page, which was checking to see if it existed in the page directory. Hwoops.

Thanks anyway, StackOverflow! Today I shall be conquering it myself. =D